# How does half a dozen remain?

Tags: riddle, mathematics

> If from six you take nine, and from nine you take ten,
> (You youths, now the mystery explain;)
> And if fifty from forty be taken, there then
> Shall just half a dozen remain.

<sub>The above puzzle appeared in the book, “Rational amusement for winter evenings” (1821) by John Jackson.</sub>

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes the answer of course would be

> SIX (Half a dozen)

If from six you take nine, and

> SIX - IX (Roman numerals for 9) = S

from nine you take ten,

> IX - X = I (All Roman numerals)

And if fifty from forty be taken

> XL - L = X (Again all Roman numerals)

Shall just half a dozen remain

> SIX